# Python Pandas: Dataframe to PDF table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdfkit, pandas-styles

I want to make a table from pandas' data frame. For that, I have used html rendring process and then writing it to pdf using pdfkit.
There is one function that checks the value of each cell and if the value is greater than 1 the color of the cell will be red otherwise green.
I am able to get the table but the problem is when the size increases from 1 page, the title is being overwritten on column data and the cell are divided between two pages.
It would be a great help if anyone gives an idea to solve this problem or any other way I can export Pandas data frame to PDF table. Please find the code below. Thanks in advance for any tip.

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pdfkit
import PyPDF2
import docx
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
import datetime 
import math
from IPython.display import display, HTML, display_html
from itertools import chain,cycle


#open the html file to fill it with the data
f = open('exp.html','w')


test1 =  {'Cl1': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
        'Cl2':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
        'Cl3': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], 
        'Cl4': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                                     1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]}

test1 = pd.DataFrame(test1)
test1.index += 1


def bk_color_cell(cell):
   return 'background-color: ' + ('red' if cell > 0 else 'green')

html = test1.style.applymap(bk_color_cell).render()

print (html)

f.write(html)
f.close()
pdfkit.from_file('exp.html', 'out1.pdf')
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. My secondary page headers come through fine. `pdfkit 0.6.1`, `pandas 1.3.3`. Perhaps this is a version specific issue? Can you share the reproducible versions?

Comment: @HenryEcker I have the same pdfkit version, but pandas 1.2.4. I will update the pandas and will try.

Comment: @HenryEcker I have tried matching the version of pdfkit and pandas, but still the same problem. I am using Anaconda Spyder 4.2.5, 64 bit. Can it have an effect?